# Testing with Internet Explorer on Selenium Grid with node as Windows service

Tags: selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, windows-server-2012, selenium-grid

We have build several Selenium tests of our corporate portal. The next step is to test on a Selenium Grid setup. We have access to a Hub and a Node which are started as a service on a Windows Server. We can connect to the Hub and the tests are started on the Node.

Because the Node is started as a service the tests are executed in the background. The tests have to be executed in IE11 because the portal only works correctly on that browser. So far so good.

Only our tests of the portal do not execute properly. The portal is made in Tibco and contains ActiveX elements and a lot of scripts. 
We tried several possible solutions:

- Started the service (of the node) with an actual user instead of the System user
- Lowered all security settings
- Switched protected mode in all area's
- Added the portal url to the Trusted Sites

But nothing worked. 
We also tried a test on a very simpel website with only a textbox and a button and that worked. Also when we navigate to the portal from the server where the node is located everything works fine. 
Only when the tests are executed from the background it looks like the website cannot be properly loaded.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? Or does anyone know how to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Why are you using a Windows service? Running the IE driver from a Windows service context is expressly unsupported. If your answer is, “To make sure the node is started when the machine is rebooted,” or, “To avoid having a logged-in user session on the node machine,” you’ll need to adjust your expectations.

Comment: Good question. We thought that when we use a service we can run multiple tests simultaniously. But is that also possible when we run the node in the foreground?

Comment: Avoid running automation agents as services. You'll encounter a very long list of issues and eventually switch to an agent as a regular desktop process. Running as a service won't help you parallelize.